# Convert serialized Java object to human readable

Tags: java, binary, bc, ascii, hexdump

I have object of class

```
class X { 
  private DateTime dt; 

  "constructor, set/get" 
}
```

I have one instance of this object serialized in `file.bin`.

I want to show content of `file.bin on the Linux console in human readable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display the contents of a file with `cat`, but with binary files that will often result in "garbage". For binary files you can use `od -x` (or `xxd`):

```
od -x file.bin
```

that makes everything byte readable as hex words for **any** file (understanding what that means is more difficult and dependent on the program that wrote the file, but fortunately that is not what you asked for).

Comment: Tiny: `od` defaults to octal words; for hex bytes use `-t x1`. Also: Java serialized data is defined mostly by the Java infrastructure and not by the application: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html (or earlier).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for pointing that out, I'm mostly using `xxd`, but that doesn't seem to be available everywhere. An application still determines which library/framework/service it uses to write out the binary, few frameworks do anything without an application, so the app IMO still determines what happens (but that is semantics).